# function to generate array of numbers that sum up to inputed number

Tags: python

I know this seems silly but I need to create a function `generate_sum_array(seed,factor)` that will create an array of any number of elements arranged in random order  in which all the array elements sum up to `seed` and have each have element is divisible by `factor`
For example:
`generate_sum_array(100.10)`
should return something like
`[20,10,40,10,20]`  or `[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]` or  `[50,20,10,20,]` etc.  as long as the sum of all the elements is `100` the seed
There can be unlimited possibilities (I think.....I am not really sure....How many different arrays can be generated)

Comment: What if `seed` is `101` and `factor` is `10`, what is the output then?

Comment: @AndrejKesely well in my context, it can never be that.

Comment: @AndrejKesely oTHERS may just remove the factor part

Answer (score 0):

The most simple function you can do that complies with your restiction is:

```
def generate_sum_array(seed,factor):
    return [factor for i in range(seed // factor)] if seed % factor == 0 else None
```

Any other valid combination is just made of sums of the list returned

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
def generate_sum_array(seed, factor):
    if seed%factor:
        raise ValueError("Seed and factor are inconsistent")
    remnant = seed
    arr = []
    while(remnant):
        val = randint(1, remnant/factor)*factor
        arr.append(val)
        remnant-=val
    return arr
```